# In Share point Open Site page as list new item form?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

In Share point 2010, when list add new item click, it redirect to another page for add new item

Comment: This is not a question. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints.

Answer (score 0):

For any List in Sharepoint, there can be three main web parts, that are Display, New and Edit. As you can guess, each of them carries a template to either display the fields of selected item or present you UI to either create a new item or edit currently selected item. 
So by default when you click on new item when on List page it carries you to New Form Webpart.
Hope this answer or try to right the question with more details.